# In Dyalog APL, can an Reduce N-Wise be a function or is it just an expression?

Tags: apl, dyalog

Say I want to name a function (assign to a variable) that does n-wise (2 in this example) reduction. Using tryapl.org it looks like I can't:

```
      v←⍳5
      2,/v
┌───┬───┬───┬───┐
│1 2│2 3│3 4│4 5│
└───┴───┴───┴───┘
      2,/
SYNTAX ERROR: Missing right argument
      2,/
       ∧
```

When I evaluate `2,/` I expect to get a little ASCII train tree something like this:

```
      -,/
┌┴┐
- /
┌─┘
,
```

It seems like `2,/` works as an expression but not as a nameable function -- is that right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but it has to form one of two patterns:

1. A 3-train (fork) `Agh`
2. A function with a bound argument `A∘g`

#### A 3-train (fork) `Agh`

This is an array `A`, a function `g`, and a function `h`, where `h` is applied monadically to the overall argument, and `g` is applied dyadically to the result of `g`, with `A` as `g`'s left argument. Since `,/` is dyadic with the `2` as left argument, we have an extra function `h` pre-processing the argument. We don't need any pre-processing, so we use an identity function:

```
      v←⍳5
      f←2,/⊢
      f
┌─┼──┐
2 ,/ ⊢
      f v
┌───┬───┬───┬───┐
│1 2│2 3│3 4│4 5│
└───┴───┴───┴───┘
```

[More about Forks on APL Wiki.](https://apl.wiki/Fork)

#### A function with a bound argument `A∘g`

Here, we use the Bind operator `∘` to curry a constant argument to a dyadic function. Our constant is `2` and the function `g` is `,/` but since operators like `/` have long left scope `2∘,/` would be parsed as `(2∘,)/` which isn't what we want, so we have to parenthesise `,/`:

```
      v←⍳5
      f←2∘(,/)
      f
 ∘
┌┴┐
2 ,/
      f v
┌───┬───┬───┬───┐
│1 2│2 3│3 4│4 5│
└───┴───┴───┴───┘
```

[More about Bind on APL Wiki.](https://apl.wiki/Bind)